# Having trouble using the modulo operator with a method

Tags: ruby, debugging, modulo

I have two methods turn_count(board) and current_player(board). The turn_count(board) method, which returns the number of "X"s and "O"s in an array is working appropriately. But the current_player(board) method, which is supposed to puts "X" if turn_count(board) is even and "O" if turn_count(board) is odd keeps giving me an error. The error is:

/Users/john/Desktop/test file.rb:13:in `current_player': undefined method`%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/john/Desktop/test file.rb:18:in `'

Clearly it's saying there's an issue with the modulo operator being used, but i'm not sure why and have been wracking my brain trying to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def turn_count(board)
      count = 0
    board.each do |x| if x == "X" || x == "O" 
      count = count + 1
    end
  end
    puts count
end 


def current_player(board)
  if turn_count(board) % == 0
     puts "X"
  else
     puts "O"
  end 
end
```

Comment: On my machine, `turn_count(board) % == 0` results in a syntax error. Please check your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using % on a NilClass. Your turn_count() method returns nil. Check what happens if you replace puts count with count.

Comment: thank you very much! that worked and i learned about nil class.

Comment: No problem, could you accept my answer?

Comment: You mean it no longer puts a string with '3' for example. The above method should return 3. With puts you print the output in the console, but that shouldn't be necessary. Are you using Ruby with Rails?

Comment: it doesn't matter any way. thank you!